# About the number of specific elements in a finite group $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be a finite group, and let $S$ be the set of all the elements of $G$ which are not equal to their own inverse: $S = \{x \in G: x \neq x^{-1}\}.$  The set $S$ can be divided up into pairs so that each element is paired off with its own inverse. Prove the following:

> In any finite group $G$, the number of elements not equal to their own inverse is an
>   even number.

Only sets with an even number of elements can be partitioned into subsets of two. Further, $\frac {|G|}{2} $ is an even number, so the number of elements not equal to their own inverse is an even number.

> The number of elements of $G$ equal to their own inverse is odd or even, depending
>   on whether the number of elements in $G$ is odd or even.

If $|G|$ is odd, then there's at least $1$ element in $G$ that equals its own inverse. If $|G|$ is even, then there are at least $2$ elements in $G$ that equal their own inverse.

> If the order of $G$ is even, there is at least one element $x$ in $G$ such that $x \neq e$ and $x = x^{-1}.$

If $|G|$ is even, then there are at least two $x$'s in $G$ such that $x = x^{-1}$. Neither of these $x$'s, then, can be equal to $e$.

---

Please, check my reasoning.

Comment: Your first line of reasoning does not make sense. $|G|$ need not be even, so how can you say with certainty that $|G|/2$ is an integer, let alone an even integer? Furthermore, what impact does $|G|/2$ have on the size of $S$? Your second line of reasoning is not quite right and borders on assuming what you're trying to prove. Instead, note that the set of elements which equal their own inverse is $G \setminus S$, which has cardinality $|G|-|S|$. The third is not quite right either. Why must both $x$'s not equal $e$ (one of them certainly could be $e$ - take the cyclic group of order $4$)?

Comment: For the first one, $\frac {|S|}{2}$ is even. Every subset of $S$ contains an element that is not equal to its own inverse, so there is an even number of such elements in $G$. Does that make sense?

Comment: Why are you trying to say $|S|/2$ is even? It isn't true necessarily, and your goal is to prove the /weaker/ statement that $|S|$ is even. You're on the right track. Here's the basic idea. Pair up each element in $G$ with its inverse. Let $K$ be the set of such pairings $(x, y)$ such that $x \neq y$. Each element in each pair of $K$ is a member of $S$, and since each pair in $K$ contributes two *distinct* elements to $S$, we have $|S| = 2|K|$, i.e. $|S|$ is even.

Comment: Yes, that is correct. (You want to type \setminus instead of  \, since MathJax interprets the latter as the beginning of a command/macro).

Comment: Since $|S|$ is even, $|G \setminus S|$ is even if $|G|$ is even and $|G \setminus S|$ is odd if $|G|$ is odd. Is that correct? edit: sorry, I had to redo it. :)

Comment: No problem, looks good! :)

Comment: $|G|$ being even implies that $|G \setminus S|$ is even, so there's at least one $x$ with $x = x^{-1}.$ Thus, $xx = e$, so this particular $x$ is not $e$. Is that correct?

Comment: Not quite, if I understand you correctly. How/why do you conclude $xx^{-1}=e$ means $x$ is not $e$? You're correct that $|G|$ even implies $|G \setminus S|$ is even, but the set of even numbers includes $0$. The key is in realizing $e \in G \setminus S$, since $e^{-1} = e$, so in particular $G \setminus S$ is nonempty. Hence, since it's even, we must have $|G \setminus S| \geq 2$, and so there exists $x \in G\setminus S$ such that $x \neq e$.

Comment: Are we implicitly assuming that since $e$ is unique and that $e$ already equals $e^{-1}$, $x$ can't be $e$? Is it possible that $x = e^{-1}$?

Comment: No assumptions necessary. We're asserting the existence of such an $x$ that isn't $e$ (and isn't $e^{-1}$ either, since $e=e^{-1}$). $|G\setminus S|$ is even as noted, so $|G\setminus S|$ must be one of $0, 2, 4, 6, \ldots$ etc. We know that $e \in |G\setminus S|$, so $|G \setminus S|$ isn't $0$. This is all we need, since that means that $|G \setminus S|$ must be $2$ or greater, i.e. there exists $x \in G$ such that $\{e, x\} \subset G\setminus S$. Does this make sense to you?

Comment: I understand everything up to the fact that $G \setminus S$ has at least $2$ elements. Let me try and reason further. Since $e \in G \setminus S$, the other element must be $x$. Suppose $x = e$. Then there's only $1$ element in $G \setminus S$, but we know there are at least $2$. So, $x \neq e$. Does that make sense?